# Weird issue with Output in C

Tags: c, struct, character

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct agent
{
    char name[30];
    int  age;
} list[20];

main()
{
    struct agent getData();
    char         ch;
    int          i = 0;
    int          j;

    puts("1. Enter More");
    puts("2. Display");
    puts("3. Exit");

    while ((ch = getchar()) < '3')
    {
        if (ch == '1')
        {
            list[i++] = getData();
        }
        else if (ch == '2')
        {
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                puts(list[j].name);
                printf("%d\n", list[j].age);
            }
        }

        puts("1. Enter More");
        puts("2. Display");
        puts("3. Exit");
    }
}

struct agent getData(
{
    struct agent tmp;

    puts("Enter name");
    scanf(" %s",tmp.name);
    puts("Enter age");
    scanf("%d",&tmp.age);

    return tmp;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1. Enter More
2. Display
3. Exit
1
Enter name
ace
Enter age
23
1. Enter More
2. Display
3. Exit
1. Enter More
2. Display
3. Exit
3
```

why are these statements 
"1. Enter More
2. Display
3. Exit "
getting repeated??

Comment: Because you are not supposed to get user input using `scanf()` (at least not until you entirely understand how it works, which, assuming you're a beginner, won't be true until a few years later.)

Comment: because you are using them in the while loop. This is a simple thing to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getData()` does *not* consume the newline char after your input. Thus, it is consumed on the next `getchar()` invocation. Since `\n` is "less than" the ascii-value of the `int` literal `'3'`, but is neither `'1'` or `'2'`, your menu prints again.

You can address this a number of ways, including having `getData()` consume the *entire* line, including the newline, or make the loop in `main` considerably smarter. Either way, make sure you know what you're testing *valid data* against `'3'`.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing an char like a int.

try this:

```
while (ch=getchar())!='3')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip trailing newline from previous `scanf`
which get consumed as input for the next `getchar`

Use:

```
int c;

while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c != EOF ); //eats newline came from scanf
```

after last `scanf` call

Comment: @haccks in `getData()`

Comment: Condider that comment was a joke :D

Answer (score 1):

> why are these statements "1. Enter More 2. Display 3. Exit " getting repeated??

Because of the newline character left behind by `scanf` in `getdata()` after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Try this to eat up all the `'\n'`.

```
while ((ch=getchar()) != '3') {

    while((ch=getchar())!='\n' && ch != EOF ); //to eatup the newline
    if (ch == '1')  
    ....
```